# Symfony2 security functions in Twig? How to check the user's role?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have Symfony 2.0.9 standard edition installed with JMSSecurityBundle.  Just wondering what functions are available to me in a Twig template to deal with users?

Specifically I want check to see if a user has the role ROLE_ADMIN.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, found it: is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')

Answer (score 256, accepted):

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} ... {% endif %}
```

Comment: Note that is_granted uses the roles on the current session: so if you have a new role and didn't login/out it will not work!