# Twig: show something if user has roleX in a user list (not the current user).

Tags: symfony, twig

In Symfony 4, I have a couple of different roles. I have a view in Twig which shows a user list. Users can have multiple roles. In the list, I want to show some text if a user has a role "MANAGER". Showing all roles is done with:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {{ role }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now if the user has the role "MANAGER" I want to show some text. I tried:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {% if (role is "MANAGER") %}
        Show some text.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but this returns the error

> Unexpected token "string" of value "MANAGER" ("name" expected).

Same error is shown when I use `{% if is "MANAGER") %}` and when I use     `{% if "MANAGER") %}` for some reason `Show some text.` is shown for every role the user has, no matter which role that is. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to your self posted answer: a single role is not an array, the containment operator (see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator) supports checks for substrings as well, that's what happening here.

So you check works, but might have false-positives if you have for example a role "MINI_MANAGER", e.g.

```
{% set role = "MINI_MANAGER" %}
{% if "MANAGER" in role %}
    Some text here.
{% endif %}
```

will also output "Some text here.". So the better solution would be:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {% if role == "MANAGER" %}
    Some text here.     
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This could still lead to problems when role is the boolean value "true" (that is not a Twig problem, but normal PHP behavior), so you can also have a look into the "same as" test, see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {% if role is same as("MANAGER") %}
    Some text here.     
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. Although your answer makes perfect sense, I cannot get the desired effect. When I use your code (either the first or second suggestion) no text 'some text here' is rendered. No error either btw.

Comment: I am somewhat of an idiot. The role is actually called "ROLE_MANAGER" and not "MANAGER", which is why I did not get the result. Finally figured that out...

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I have figured it out. It seems every single role is in fact an array, so you have to check for the value within the array like this:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {% if "MANAGER" in role %}
    Some text here.     
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am still not sure why a single role is an array though, but there surely is a reason for that.

Comment: Can you show how you modeled your `User` class and how roles are associated to it? This might explain the behaviour.

Comment: I am using the FOSUser bundle. For new "manager" users I use a lazy way to give them this role with the contruct method: `$this->roles = array('ROLE_MANAGER');`

Comment: @xabbuh, I figured out what I did wrong. The role is not "MANAGER" but "ROLE_MANAGER". That's why it did not work. Such an elementary mistake...

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') %} 
   Some text here 
{% endif %}
```

Source: [Symfony2 security functions in Twig? How to check the user's role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810284/symfony2-security-functions-in-twig-how-to-check-the-users-role)

[See also Symfony Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security.html#roles)

> Roles: When a user logs in, they receive a set of roles (e.g.
>   ROLE_ADMIN).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I am not looking for the permissions of the user that is viewing the page, I want to show something in a list of users next to users with the role "MANAGER".